# Fourier transform involving a dirac delta function

Tags: fourier-analysis, mathematical-physics

I know that $\int \delta(x-a)f(x) dx =f(a) $ , the fundamental defining property of the delta function. How does this change if we no longer consider $x-a$ but $a^2 -x^2$, such that the integral is now
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(a^2 -x^2)f(x) dx$?
Thank you for any help in advance

Comment: is that  what you mean or there is something different?i have tried to answer this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can look on this formula

[image]

now you can apply sum formula and you should get

$f(a)/(|2*a|)+f(-a)/|2*a|$

also imagine that $(a-x)=-(x-a)$

Comment: @user1887919 to make sure  about answer,it is correct right?because i have not seen this in the books,that why not to accept maybe wrong answer,is it correct?

Comment: does this hold if f(x) is complex? I'm considering fourier transforms so suppose f(x)=(1/x^2)*e^(-ibx) where b is a constant, would your method still apply?

Comment: where did you find this problem?

Comment: It's just hypothetical... trying to get my head around Fourier transforms so just making up different questions

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/154341/fourier-transform-of-delta-fucntion  please see this,i dont know also exactly,i ahev combined your question and my answer,let us wait please ok?

Comment: i am also interested,mine is also hypothetical answer,just you can upvote to get  reputation 3400

Comment: they are crazy,every time i posting questions there,i am fighting with them

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/154346/modified-delta-function-and-its-feature there it is

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'd be really interested to know the answer been tearing my hair out for hours!

Comment: yes but they are mad persons,they are dowvoting why i dont know

Comment: i have reposted question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/154347/generalized-functions-and-their-fourier-trasnform

Comment: @user1887919 please repost question ok?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/635904/check-answer-on-given-qesution

Comment: @user1887919  please look there http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/635904/check-answer-on-given-question/635958#635958